# Create and delete cookies in php

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to create and delete cookie in php but I am unable to do so. I have gone through php official site but even that did not resolve my issue.

The code that I have written:

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "cookie_id";

if (!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]))
{
    echo "Inside if: ".$_COOKIE[$cookie_name];

    $unique_id = date('ymdhis').''.uniqid('', true);
    
    setcookie($cookie_name, $unique_id);
    setcookie($cookie_name, $unique_id, strtotime( '+30 days' ) );
    setcookie($cookie_name, $unique_id, strtotime( '+30 days' ) , "/", "www.domain.in", 1);
}
echo "Current: ".$_COOKIE[$cookie_name];

setcookie ($cookie_name, "", time() - 3600);
setcookie ($cookie_name, "", time() - 3600, "/", "www.domain.in", 1);

echo "</br>";
echo "After Reset: ".$_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
?>
```

Basically I am trying to create and delete the cookie on the same page and then recreate it on next page load.

I have already referred: [https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php][1] but cant get through.

This is what output I get:

```
Inside if: Current: 
After Reset:
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php -> `Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your script (this is a protocol restriction). This requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output, including <html> and <head> tags as well as any whitespace.`. So `echo "Inside if: ".$_COOKIE[$cookie_name];` will send output, so `setcookie($cookie_name, $unique_id);` will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the PHP documentation you linked:

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load

You are trying to read the cookie too quickly, you're setting it and then deleting it before it even makes it to the user.

Comment: Yes I separated the create cookie and delete cookie on different pages and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this to delete cookie

```
setcookie($cookie_name, null, null);
```